# Unable to write into user settings. I can not turn on autosave

Tags: visual-studio-code

please help,

This is what the settings in my json has. I am unable to turn on autosave.
the error seems to be where the colon is after "launch" on the first line.
I am no sure if that is where the actual error is.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Local Node File",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        },
    ]
}{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

Comment: So your question is how to turn on auto save or how to solve the error?

Comment: well there was an error preventing auto- save . So ideally I wanted to do both but, maybe the first would be an effect of solving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - this is the **ENTIRE** `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Local Node File",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        }
    ]
  },

  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

The `launch` setting goes within the outer json `{}` delimiters.  And then the other settings follow also within those outer brackets as I have shown it.

You had another `{` before the other settings.  And no `"launch: {` before the `version`, etc. part (although you mention it you don't show it).  `launch` is part of that setting.